# Facing issues deserializing JSON into .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

I'm relatively new to dealing with JSON. But have successfully created a few classes that return exactly what I want. However, this response is baffling me.

I have reviewed and attempted the various examples on the site to convert my JSON response into a class. However, I continue to get run-time errors.
Any pointers on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

**JSON Response**

```
{
    "locationResponse": {
        "locations": [
            "E911AID:93a6:2db4:0589:261d,streetDir:NE,street:89th,zip:98052,city:Redmond,streetNameSuffix:St,name:Jonathon Doe,state:WA,houseNum:23619",
            "E911AID:93a6:2db4:0589:261d,streetDir:NE,street:89th,zip:98052,city:Redmond,streetNameSuffix:St,name:Jon Doe,state:WA,houseNum:23619",
            "ad1c:2dbf:fadf:2e87",
            "E911AID:93a6:2db4:0589:261d,streetDir:NE,street:89th,zip:98052,city:Redmond,streetNameSuffix:St,name:John Doe,state:WA,houseNum:23619",
            "E911AID:93a6:2db4:0589:261d,streetDir:NE,street:89th,zip:98052,city:Redmond,streetNameSuffix:St,name:JJ Doe,state:WA,houseNum:23619"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Class Definition**

```
[Serializable]
public class locationResponseResponse
{
    public locationResponse locationResponse { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class locationResponse
{
    public location[] locations { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class location
{
    public string E911AID { get; set; }
    public string streetDir { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string streetNameSuffix { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string houseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialize Snippet**

```
public locationResponseResponse GetlocationResponseResponse(string jsonString)
{
    locationResponseResponse _response = new locationResponseResponse();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        _response = ser.Deserialize<locationResponseResponse>(jsonString);
    }
    return _response;
}
```

**Run-time Error Received**

No parameterless constructor defined for type of `BlackFlagAPI.locationResponse[]`.

Comment: Consider using Newtsoft.Json. It's the most popular json serializer.

Comment: The `location`s in the json example are strings, not json objects. So a json deserializer can't turn them into your `location` class. You'll need to register a custom parser for that.

Comment: Next time you post json, please use pretty printed json. Makes it much easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I fixed your JSON, this one works fine: https://gist.github.com/cubrr/ac9b70961301193caf49

Answer (score 2):

The `location`s in the json example are strings, not json objects. So a json deserializer can't turn them into your `location` class. The string content isn't a serialized json document either.

You'll need to register a custom parser for that, but since I never worked with `JavascriptSerializer`, I can't tell you how.

Alternatively, if you have control over the source of the json, encode the location data using json instead of embedding a custom format in a string.

Answer (score 0):

For the JSON that you have posted, the class would be similar to below:

```
public class LocationResponse
{
    public List<string> locations { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
     public LocationResponse locationResponse { get; set; }
}
```

You would need to then manually parse the locations. Else, you need to correct the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

`Locations` in your json is not json objects. They are strings in the form `name:value` separated by `,`.

So you need to parse it in two steps

1- Deserialize the json

```
var root = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
```

2- Parse each string

```
var addrs = root.locationResponse.locations
                .Select(x => x.Split(','))
                .Select(parts =>
                {
                    var l = new Location();
                    var props = l.GetType().GetProperties();
                    foreach (var part in parts)
                    {
                        var kv = part.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
                        var prop = l.GetType().GetProperty(kv[0]);
                        if(prop != null)
                            prop.SetValue(l, kv[1]);

                    }
                    return l;
                })
                .ToList();
```

---

```
public class Location
{
    public string E911AID { get; set; }
    public string streetDir { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string streetNameSuffix { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string houseNum { get; set; }
}

public class LocationResponse
{
    public List<string> locations { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public LocationResponse locationResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, upon more digging it appears the service I'm getting the JSON response has a bug. I hadn't noticed the near-empty row containing only an ID. This seems to be the crux of the issue. Once I dropped this bad line, even my original code worked.  Now I need to determine if JSON output is flawed, and potentially fix inline or simply error out.  Really appreciate all the assistance.